# Why can't I see the new group that I belong to when opening a new terminal?

Tags: login, virtual-terminal

I added myself to a new group

```
sudo usermod -a -G theGroup $USER
```

and *then* opened a *new* terminal. I expected that `id` would reflect my new membership in `theGroup`, but it didn't.

However, when I do `su - $USER` I *can* see the membership in `theGroup`.

This puzzles me because I thought that opening a new terminal is essentially similar to `su - $USER`.

When I execute `groups $USER` in the the terminal session, I cannot see the new group, when I execute it in the `su - $USER` terminal, I can see it.

Comment: what is the output of `groups $USER` ?

Comment: you usually need to logout / login again to see the new group membership

Answer (score 3):

group changes are not visible in existing shells.

they only showup in login shells after the change.

Its simplest just to logout your desktop session and login again.

or you can run this to simulate a login shell

```
bash -l
```